# Output a pointer to stdout in x86?

Tags: assembly

So I have the following code, which allocates memory using the mmap linux system call.  After executing these instructions, the pointer to the allocated memory is stored in eax.  How can I print this pointer in a human readable form such as "00ffbfff".

I understand how to print to stdout using the write system call, but I was wondering how to convert the value stored in eax to its hexidecimal representation.

```
section .text
 global _start

_start:

  ; mmap struct

  push 0        ; 
  push -1       ; set the file dsc to -1 for MAP_ANONYMOUS
  push 0x20     ; set MAP_ANONYMOUS
  push 0x07     ; set Protections WRX
  push 0x04     ; size to allocate
  push 0        ; geuss - Not Applicable

  ;; syscall 

  push eax, 90  ; mmap opcode
  push ebx, esp ; mmap struct
  int 0x80      ; execute the system call

  ; allocated address in in eax
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you'll need to write your own int-to-text routine, or you can just link the standard runtime library and call the `printf()` system call. You'll have to read up on how your assembler handles linked library functions and importing their symbols and the calling convention, but any C function can be called from assembly if you know what you're doing.